# VirtueMart 3.0.18 Registration Issue

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, email, virtuemart, user-registration

I have a problem when it comes to registration as in confirmation was not sent to my email. Aside from this, it keeps returning to the registration page, no progress at all. What shall I do?

Anyway I'm using Joomla 3.6.2 with VM 3.0.18 installed

Answer (score 0):

To start at somewhere:
 1. Make sure that mailer is configured under Global Configuration \ server \ Mail Settings.
 2. See if mails are sent locally. Webservers like Open server or Denwer have an option to get your emails locally, dumped to some folder as files.
 3. Also see if options for Virtuemart registering are okay.

Comment: I used SMTP as my mailer, here's my host: smtp.mandrillapp.com, port: 587, SMTP Security:none, SMTP Authentication: yes, so how do I know that Virtuemart registering will be okay?

Comment: @KyleTorreVillar, first off: pls make sure that your Joomla is able to use Mandrill as smtp. I guess , that you've  read [link](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582217-How-to-Send-Mandrill-Email-with-Popular-CMS-Providers) and set it up, and paid for it, etc, etc.

Comment: second: check out what access.log and error.log are saying. Painful at first, but helpful.

Comment: also, 'returning to the registration page' or not going anywhere? Got no action at all? Check the console for JS errors too. You 've got to narrow down the bug somehow..